# Проверка на то, является ли год високосным

Tags: c#

Как на языке C# можно узнать, является ли год високосным?

Есть какая-нибудь функция для этого? Если есть, то как она реализована внутри?

Comment: Надо бы принять какой-нибудь ответ.

Answer (score 10):

На самом деле вопрос не так прост, как кажется.

Самый простой способ проверки - это вызов [`DateTime.IsLeapYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(2000)
```

Который [реализован](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,3c149093001ab007) примерно так:

```
return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
```

Но дело в том, что понятие "високосный год", как и сама нумерация лет, сильно отличаются от культуры к культуре. А .NET не ограничивается только Григорианским календарем.

Поэтому более общий и правильный способ проверки високосности года - вызов `IsLeapYear(year)` или `IsLeapYear(year, era)` у соответствующего наследника класса [`System.Globalization.Calendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Наследников таких аж 10 штук (в текущей версии фреймворка). И реализация проверки на високосность в них достаточно разнообразная.

Например, в [юлианском календаре](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/juliancalendar.cs,96697098917d1482) проверка простая как тапок:

```
return (year % 4 == 0);
```

А вот в `HebrewCalendar` проверка на високосность [выглядит достаточно оригинально](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/hebrewcalendar.cs,0c51cc9736bbce5e):

```
 return (((7 * (long)year + 1) % 19) < 7);
```

и в високосном году может быть 383, 384 а иногда и 385 дней.

Впрочем, там весь файл [HebrewCalendar.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/hebrewcalendar.cs) достоин того, чтобы его распечатать и повесить в рамке на стену.

`HijriCalendar` тоже вводит [достаточно странное условие високосности](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/hijricalendar.cs,683a38f7884eb90d):

```
return ((((year * 11) + 14) % 30) < 11);
```

А вот в 4-х наследниках класса [`EastAsianLunisolarCalendar`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/eastasianlunisolarcalendar.cs,dd7c8a80598ba8ec,references) проблема тупо решена [хардкодом количества дней в месяцах](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/chineselunisolarcalendar.cs,dbad04448ef77c99,references) для всех лет от 1912 до 2050. Судя по всему, количество дней в году для этих календарей не поддается алгоритмизации :). И список високосных лет придется просто выучить наизусть.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    return ( year % 4 == 0 ) && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 );
}
```

То же самое можно переписать по-другому

```
public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    return ( year % 400 == 0 ) || ( year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0 );
}
```

Имейте в виду, что класс `DateTime` уже имеет подобный статический метод `IsLeapYear`. Например результатом вывода на консоль данного предложения

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.IsLeapYear(2000));
```

будет

```
True
```